# How to share image downloaded from firebase storage between different views?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This is the code i use to fetch the image from the storage. It works like charm but i dont want to redownload it on different views again.

```
func retreiveImagesFromFireBase(downloadUrl:String,imageHolder:UIImageView){
    if downloadUrl != "" {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadUrl)
        // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
        storageRef.getData(maxSize: 5*1024*1024) { (data, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let pic = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageHolder.image = pic
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should i handle this?

Comment: Cache the image. Means: you can keep the image in the memory or/and save the image in the cache directory

Comment: Do you have more than one image used with a different view or single image?

Comment: Does firebase offline mode do that for us?

Comment: I have two images actually and both of them are used on more than three views.

Comment: hi @CaptainNewt if you have only two image then store in userdefault and then you can use anywhere, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one or two images then simply store in `userdefault` and then you can access in any viewController, Store `image` as `data` in `userdefault`
whenever you want to use just convert data to image and use it, See the following code to convert data to image

```
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare UIImage globally in your class, and inside your function, where you are setting imageHolder, assign that downloaded image to global image, and use it where ever you want.

```
UIImage image;

func retreiveImagesFromFireBase(downloadUrl:String,imageHolder:UIImageView){
            if downloadUrl != ""{
                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: downloadUrl)
                // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 5*1024*1024) { (data, error) in
                    if error == nil{
                        if let pic = UIImage(data: data!){
                            imageHolder.image = pic
                            image = pic // use it on other views 
                        }
                    }else{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
class Service { 
   static let shared = Service()  
   var image1:UIImage?
   var image2:UIImage?
   let imageLink = "//////" // or with SDWebImage
}

if let pic = UIImage(data: data!){
    Service.shared.image = pic
}
```

Or use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) and share the link , you can aslo make a global var like

```
var image:UIImage?
```

but it's not recommended as it has no grouping to let the developer know it's source local/instance/global so it's confusing unlike  singleton

Comment: I cant use third party libraries because my storage rules doesnot allow them too fetch the files and i want securities so i cant change the rules.

Comment: should i add two UIImage variables in that class.